# Can installing Autoptimize affect Google Adsense script?

Tags: wordpress

Does installing Autoptimize cache plugin in Wordpress mess up with Google Adsense script, and can prevent Adsense from detecting clicks on the ads?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, but carefull to not encapsulate your Google Adsense script in the JS minify function from Autoptimize

Comment: How can this be done? By default all js is minified yes?